# How bash IFS is working in this example?

Tags: bash, ifs

I am reading about [bash internal variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) and came across this `IFS` example:

```
output_args_one_per_line()
{
  for arg
  do
    echo "[$arg]"
  done #  ^    ^   Embed within brackets, for your viewing pleasure.
}
```

**CASE1**

```
IFS=" "
var=" a  b c   "

output_args_one_per_line $var
#OUTPUT
# [a]
# [b]
# [c]
```

**CASE2**

```
IFS=:
var=":a::b:c:::"               # Same pattern as above
CASE2   
                        # but substituting ":" for " "  ...
output_args_one_per_line $var
# []
# [a]
# []
# [b]
# [c]
# []
# []
```

Now, according to my understanding if value of `IFS` is default `\t\n` than leading and trailing whitespaces are removed. So, for case1 bash sees `var` as `a b c` therefore the output.

For case2 according to me bash sees `var` as `|a||b|c|||` treat `|` as `space` here. I checked it using

```
Noob@Noob:~/tmp$ IFS=$':' FOO=$":a::b:c:::"; echo $FOO $'x'
 a  b c   x
```

So, my expected output for case 2 is

```
# []
# [a]
# []
# []
# [b]
# [c]
# []
# []
# []
```

So, can someone explain to me internally how bash is treating `var` in case 2 and where am I going wrong iin my understanding.

Comment: OT: your output_args_one_per_line function could be replaced by `printf "[%s]\n" $var`

Comment: look at the split as presented with `bash -x` when `var` is expanded. see the edit on my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On *case 2* you have `":a::b:c:::"` with `IFS=:`
so what you are doing is splitting the string in each met `:`

so, from the beginning of the string, till the first `:` you have `":`
which is *nothing*, thus `[]`

from the first `:` to the next `:` you have `:a:`
which is `a`, thus `[a]`

from there to the next `:` you have `::`
which is *nothing*, thus `[]`

from there to the next `:` you have `:b:`
which is `b`, thus `[b]`

from there to the next `:` you have `:c:`
which is `c`, thus `[c]`

from there to the next `:` you have `::`
which is *nothing*, thus `[]`

from there to the next `:` you have `::"`
which is *nothing*, thus `[]`

so you get that result..

---

as @Mark Reed mentioned in the comments you can use `printf`
along with `bash -x` you get:

```
$ bash -x
$ IFS=':'; var=':a::b:c:::'; printf "[%s]\n" $var
[12]+ IFS=:
[12]+ var=:a::b:c:::
[12]+ printf '[%s]\n' '' a '' b c '' ''     # notice this
[]
[a]
[]
[b]
[c]
[]
[]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your claim (edited to use ':' instead of '|'):

> For case2 according to me bash sees var as :a::b:c::: treat : as space here.

is false. `IFS` causes `bash` to treat `:` as a word separator, not whitespace. Don't confuse the two just because whitespace is the *default* word separator.

Comment: You are right I misspoke there what I actually meant is bash changes `a:b` to `a b` using whitespace as a separator.

Answer (score 1):

`:` is the delimiter. `a:b` is split into `a` and `b`, nothing in between. In your expected behaviour, how would you encode the following?

```
[a]
[]
[b]
```

The only strange thing is there are not three empty strings at the end. This might be because

> Unquoted implicit null arguments, resulting from the expansion of parameters that have no values, are removed.

Comment: If I understand you correctly than `a::b` is treated as `a(space)(empty word)b which will result into `a[]b. Can you please elaborate a little on the `strange thing` because am a bash noob and I don't understand official docs well without an example.

Comment: you split from the beginning to next met `IFS`. Then from that point to the next met `IFS`, etc.. a string like `::` will return `[]` which is _the empty string_ because from the first `:` to the next `:` you have nothing in between, but the split takes place.

Comment: @Noob - in your expected output, you claim that `a::b` should have two empty strings between `a` and `b`, when really it should only be one..

Comment: @c00kiemon5ter: Thanks, really helpful explanation.

Comment: The removal of the trailing null argument (but not the leading one) comes from the wording of the POSIX standard.  It was reportedly hotly debated on the committee, and is an unpopular decision among many of the people who care about that sort of thing.  But it is at least consistent across the various shells (ksh, {d,}ash, zsh, etc).  It's just one of those quirks you have to account for.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is pretty simple:

```
IFS=" "
var=" a  b c   "

output_args_one_per_line $var
```

this means `output_args_one_per_line` is called with this argument(s):

```
output_args_one_per_line  a  b c
```

While parsing the command line, BASH will remove the additional white space, so the actual call will use

```
output_args_one_per_line a b c
```

i.e. multiple spaces are merged into one, the spaces before `a` will become the space between command and the first argument.

That means the spaces will be gone *before* `IFS` is applied. It also means you can't write

```
IFS=:
output_args_one_per_line:$var
```

There must be a white space after the command, not a word separator.

You can run the script with `set -x` to see the trace output (i.e. how BASH expands lines).

In the second case, the word delimiter isn't a space character, so the necessary whitespace between command and first argument isn't merged with the arguments and the line becomes

```
output_args_one_per_line :a::b:c:::
```

The only odd thing is that the output should be three empty arguments after `c` but that is probably because empty trailing arguments are removed (just like BASH removes white space after the arguments). Here is another odd output:

```
IFS=:
var=":a::b:c::: "   # Blank after C
> output_args_one_per_line $var
[]
[a]
[]
[b]
[c]
[]
[]
[ ]
```

So if `var` does contain anything after the last colon, we get the missing argument.